# Create a repetition in succesion column in pandas counting repeats of value in succession

Tags: python, pandas

I have columns called `country` and `city`. Grouping by countries I want to calculate how many times a city appears in succession.

Example input:

```
country     city
France      Paris
France      Paris
France      Nice
France      Paris
France      Paris
Germany     Munich
Germany     Berlin
Germany     Berlin
Switzerland Geneva
Switzerland Geneva
Switzerland Geneva
```

Example output:

```
country     city    repetition_in_succession
France      Paris   1
France      Paris   2
France      Nice    1
France      Paris   1
France      Paris   2
Germany     Munich  1
Germany     Berlin  1
Germany     Berlin  2
Switzerland Geneva  1
Switzerland Geneva  2
Switzerland Geneva  3
```

The 5th row here has `2` because we see Paris twice in a row. Note that we cannot assume that cities are unique to countries so we need to group on the country.

Also note that this question is NOT answered by [How can I do a sequential count based on column value and timestamp in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721085/how-can-i-do-a-sequential-count-based-on-column-value-and-timestamp-in-pandas) because I need the counter to restart when the city changes and changes back. This other similar question doesn't have that requirement.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the `cumcount` logic, but you need to group on the successive rows: `df.groupby(df.ne(df.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)`